# menu item <front> does not get class expanded nor active-trail when at homepage

Tags: navigation

I have a menu which has a link to the homepage in it.

This link to the homepage has subItems.
I was hoping for the menu item to expand and show the links of the lower lvl when i was at the homepage.

This does not happen.
It does expand when i'm on one of the pages of the links of the lower lvl.

Is there any way i can expand this menu item when on the frontpage?

version:
 - drupal 7.14
 - Menu   7.14

Comment: How are you adding the menu to your theme? Though code in a template file or using a block? If you add the menu via a block then the problem your describing should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `admin/structure/menu/manage/[your-menu-name]` and Enable the *show as expanded* checkbox in your parent menu item settings.

Comment: This is not what i want. That will make it so that it's always expanded, i only want it expanded when i'm on the homepage or one of it's sublinks

Comment: Currently i have made the workaround of using the show as expanded checkbox and just hiding the sub-level with jQuery when it's not supposed to be shown. This does mean that the you get to see the bar for a brief period of time and it then disapears in those cases. So i would still appreciate a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass this "issue" by creating a blank page with for example url index.html, then change front page address to index.html , then create your menu with top level pointing to index.html and it will show children elements after being clicked without any jquery manipulation.